# with this Fibonacci sequence question with instruction sets used to make a assembly code

Tags: assembly, pipeline, fibonacci, instruction-set

This is a Fibonacci sequence that I recently attempted to turn into a assembly code through the use of instruction set. I am not sure how to go about testing it and was wondering could confirm if I got this right and if not where I went wrong. Also the "." that is used does this mean I must multiply using the instruction set. Below is the question I got and my answer I have come up with. I would also like to know if I have used the correct #.

Comment: Which instruction set? That's the basic requirement with assembly questions, to identify the instruction set, as every processor does have different one (or multiple instruction sets depending on which mode of the processor is used, depending then usually on the OS and target mode). It's obvious you were given some particular instruction set for the task, was there particular physical CPU specified, or is this fictional instruction set? That also makes difference for answering "how to test", the best is to have some emulator/simulator of the particular CPU, testing with real HW is more tricky.

Comment: the "." is very likely multiplication, if it had other specific meaning in your particular domain, you should be aware of that by this point, and you wouldn't ask. (unless this is OCR of task printed/written on paper and the "+" was garbled so much, that it got recognized as ".", then it helps to see the original paper to be sure, always be a bit paranoid about OCR-ed texts, at least be aware which text was OCRed from scans/photos and which text was just produced from original input without fuzzy procedures like OCR. Then again non-OCR texts may contain typos, so... paranoid about everything?)

Comment: hi it was typical for a RISC machine sorry forgot to mention that. and thanks a lot with the second bit as i did believe it was multiplication but its not one i see very often.

Answer (score 1):

The code needs to add `(F(n-1) + F(n-2))` before multiplying `F(n) · (F(n-1) + F(n-2))`. Since `F(n-2)` doesn't need to be saved, you could add the register with `F(n-1)` to the register with `F(n-2)`, so that the sum ends up in the register that was holding `F(n-2)`.

Trivia: `F(0) = 0`, since `F(n-2) = (F(n+1) - (F(n) · F(n-1)))/F(n)`. You can also calculate `F(-1) = 1)`, but not `F(-2)` since it that ends up as `1/0` .